# Detect click on FB embedded post iframe

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe

Trying to detect click on FB embedded post with iframeTracker-jquery library.
FB has JS SDK that helps to embed post on third-party sites.

this embed code:

```html
<div class="fb-post" 
      data-href="https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=811932475541152&id=361136907287380"
      data-width="350"></div>
```

FB SDK converts it to iframe:

```html
<div fb-post>
<span>
<iframe>
....
</iframe>
</span>
</div>
```

This iframe tracker call doesn't work:

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
     $('.fb-post > span > iframe').iframeTracker({
      blurCallback: function(){
       console.log('Horray')
      }
     });
    });
```

Could you help me to understan why it happens? How can I detect click in FB post iframe?

Answer (score 2):

> [from comments] the problem with FB embedded post is that jquery iframe selector don't find them on document ready. How come?

Because only `<div class="fb-post" …></div>` *is* present in your page at load time. The SDK is loaded asynchronously, and only inserts the iframes after it is initialized.

If you want to trigger something when the SDK is done rendering those elements into the social plugins, then you can subscribe to the `xfbml.render` event; it is

> “[f]ired when FB.XFBML.parse() completes. This indicates that all of the social plugins on the page have been loaded.”

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.4 for details.

Comment: Thank you! Can't vote up, 'cause don't have enough reputation! Wish good luck!